# How to detect corner "joints" that connect elements on images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV via Python 3.7. I have a set of monochrome images that look like this:

[image]

I'd like to find all "joint points" on these images, where a "joint point" - is a center (1 pixel) of every intersection of two planks. These "joints" are roughly represented by red cicrles on the image below:

[image]

The first idea was to skeletonize the image and then find all connected edges algorythmically, but all skeletonizations technques gave me wiggly or round corners and extra "sprouts".

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize

image = cv2.imread("SOURCE_IMAGE.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
binary_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 91, 12)
skeleton = (skeletonize(binary_image//255) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Result:

[image]

The second idea was to find inner contours, approximate them to bounding points, find closest neighbours and then somehow calculate centers, but, again, Canny edge detection method gave me wiggly corners and extra points.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("SOURCE_IMAGE.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
edged = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200)
```

Result:

[image]

Are there any reliable approcahes to this problem?

Comment: Did you have a look at convolutions?

Comment: Do you mean convolutional networks? It's unlikely they'll help me here, because classes're highly imbalanced.

Comment: I meant convolutions as image processing operations. Fidning kernels that could highlight the information you're looking for (joints): https://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slight modified version of [@YunusTemurlenk's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633334/is-it-possible-to-detect-joints-that-connect-elements/60634986#60634986) approach using Python instead of C++. The idea is:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load image, convert to grayscale, [Gaussian blur](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization).
2. **Obtain horizontal and vertical line masks.** Create horizontal and vertical structuring elements with [`cv2.getStructuringElement`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) then perform [`cv2.morphologyEx`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-transformations) to isolate the lines.
3. **Find joints.** We [`cv2.bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) the two masks together to get the joints.
4. **Find centroid on joint mask.** We [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then calculate the [centroid](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).

---

Horizontal/vertical line masks

[image]
[image]

Detected joints in green

[image]

Results

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsus threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find horizonal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,1))
horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)

# Find vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,10))
vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)

# Find joints
joints = cv2.bitwise_and(horizontal, vertical)

# Find centroid of the joints
cnts = cv2.findContours(joints, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    # Find centroid and draw center point
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    cv2.circle(image, (cx, cy), 3, (36,255,12), -1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('horizontal', horizontal)
cv2.imshow('vertical', vertical)
cv2.imshow('joints', joints)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Good approach indeed! But what about diagonal lines? I assume it's impossible to extract them correctly because angles may differ.

Comment: @SagRU the regions which both vertical and horizontal doesnt include, are the diagonals or the others. You can continue with diagonals from this point.

Comment: @nathancy what's the reason for using Gaussian blur and Otsu's threshold in this case? There'is no noise and images are always black and white, so I assume basic threshold is enough.

Comment: Gaussian blur is to ensure no small particles of noise, Otsu's threshold is to ensure its a binary image (1 channel with 0 or 255). If you just grayscale its not a binary image. Basic threshold is enough but I want to automatically calculate the threshold value so it not a hardcoded value

Comment: @nathancy Although I ended up with a different and more complex approach, I approve your solution as best of all answers (with sincere credits to Yunus Temurlenk contribution).

Comment: Any chance to update this code to OpenCV 4?

Answer (score 8):

This is my approach to solve this issue:

1. Determine vertical lines
2. Determine horizontal lines
3. Find their intersections which are joints

For first step check each column and determine thin lines and make them black(0). The result will be only vertical lines. For the second step do reverse. 
At the end compare **vertical line image** with the **horizontal line image**. The pixels which are white(255) in both are the intersection points.

***Note:*** Please do not blame me because of coding in C++. I am not familiar with python I just wanted to show my approach and results.

Here is the code and results:

Source:

[image]

Vertical Lines:

[image]

Horizontal Lines:

[image]

Result:

[image]

The code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("/ur/image/directory/joints.jpg",1);

    imshow("Source",img);

    int checker = 1,checker2 = 1;
    int begin_y,finish_y2,finish_y,begin_y2;
    Mat vertical_img = img.clone();
    Mat horizontal_img = img.clone();

    cvtColor(vertical_img,vertical_img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(horizontal_img,horizontal_img,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int finish_checker = 0,finish_checker2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<horizontal_img.rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<horizontal_img.cols;j++)
        {
            if(horizontal_img.at<uchar>(Point(j,i))>100 && checker)
            {
                begin_y = j;
                checker = 0;
            }

            if(horizontal_img.at<uchar>(Point(j,i))<20 && checker==0)
            {
                finish_y = j;
                checker = 1;
                finish_checker = 1;

            }

            if(finish_checker)
            {
                if((finish_y-begin_y)<30)
                {
                    for(int h=begin_y-2;h<=finish_y;h++)
                    {
                        horizontal_img.at<uchar>(Point(h,i)) = 0;
                    }
                }

                finish_checker = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    imshow("Horizontal",horizontal_img);

    for(int i=0;i<vertical_img.cols;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<vertical_img.rows;j++)
        {
            if(vertical_img.at<uchar>(Point(i,j))>100 && checker2)
            {
                begin_y2 = j;
                checker2 = 0;
            }
            if(vertical_img.at<uchar>(Point(i,j))<50 && checker2==0)
            {
                finish_y2 = j;
                checker2 = 1;
                finish_checker2 = 1;
            }
            if(finish_checker2)
            {
                if((finish_y2-begin_y2)<30)
                {
                    for(int h=begin_y2-2;h<=finish_y2;h++)
                    {
                        vertical_img.at<uchar>(Point(i,h)) = 0;
                    }
                }
                finish_checker2 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    imshow("Vertical",vertical_img);

    for(int y=0;y<img.cols;y++)
    {
        for(int z=0;z<img.rows;z++)
        {
            if(vertical_img.at<uchar>(Point(y,z))>200 && horizontal_img.at<uchar>(Point(y,z))>200)
            {
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(z,y)[0]=0;
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(z,y)[1]=0;
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(z,y)[2]=255;
            }
        }
    }

    imshow("Result",img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, you can go even further after you have obtained the red boxes and find the centroid to get the exact point

Comment: Yes, after red boxes with one more step centroids can be found easily too. I ll try to add it later