# How to detect biggest Grid in Image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm new to OpenCV, so please be kind :)

I'm working on a project trying to extract numbers from a formular. The preprocessing steps were kind of straight forward (with help of tutorials in the internet) but now I'm struggling applying solutions.

[image: Current version of Grid]

What I'm trying to do is, crapping the 3 biggest areas (manually painted in yellow).

My current solution for that part looks like that, this brings me only the long rectangle between 1 and (2&3), so I tried to "cheat" and calculate the grid from there.
This is why I do `x+w:image.shape[1]` in imwrite (to get the grid)...
But I can't apply that for field 2 and 3 and I bet there are more "elegent" ways.

```
finalKernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
img_bin_final=cv2.dilate(img_bin_final,finalKernel,iterations=1)
nccs, labels, stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=4, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)
for x,y,w,h,area in stats[1:]:
    if(h > 0.6*image.shape[0]):
        cv2.imwrite('Grid.png',image[y:y+h, x+w:image.shape[1]])
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: you may try the algorithm which is used in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60634986/11048887). Also sharing the source image can be better so people can try that by themselves

Comment: Thank you, good point! But I'm not sure if its helping me, as that will give me the joint points, but I have a lot of them, so not sure if that would help me actually.