# How to improve line detection with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I am trying to detect lines in an image using OpenCV (Emgu.Net implementation).
So far, results are not that bad, but it appears to me not be consistent.
For instance, as you can see from the original and the results, some lines are well captured, yet the small top vertical ones are not, despite the fact that they have the same thickness.

Here is my code:

```
 public static void ProcessImage(Mat src, bool createComposedImage)
    {
        //Convert the image to grayscale
        Mat gray = new Mat();

        CvInvoke.CvtColor(src, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

        //Use Gaussian filtering to remove noise
        CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(gray, gray, new Size(3, 3), 1);

        double cannyThreshold = 180.0;

        Mat result = new Mat();

        List<Mat> resultPortions = new List<Mat>();

        if (createComposedImage)
        {
            resultPortions.Add(src);
        }

        using (Mat cannyEdges = new Mat())
        {
            double cannyThresholdLinking = 120.0;

            CvInvoke.Canny(gray, cannyEdges, cannyThreshold, cannyThresholdLinking);


            LineSegment2D[] lines = CvInvoke.HoughLinesP(
                image: cannyEdges,
                rho: 1, //Distance resolution in pixel-related units
                theta: Math.PI / 180.0, //Angle resolution measured in radians.
                10, //threshold
                30, //min Line width
                10); //gap between lines

            if (createComposedImage)
            {
                Mat lineImage = ProcessLinesInImage(gray, lines);

                resultPortions.Add(lineImage);
            }


            if (createComposedImage)
            {
                try
                {
                    CvInvoke.VConcat(resultPortions.ToArray(), result);
                }
                catch
                {

                }

                foreach (Mat resultPortion in resultPortions)
                {
                    resultPortion.Dispose();
                }

            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

Here are the images

[image]

[image]

Comment: The min line length looks suspicious, but I also wonder whether Hough transform is overkill on an image that is *all* horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: The image above was stripped from all texts inside (it's a PDF rendered as an image). My intention is to convert the PDF to a datatable. Actually, what I am trying is to obtain coordinates to later get the texts using itext7.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60634986/11048887) may also help you to detect the lines accurately. I suggested that algorithm to find joints but works for your case also.

Comment: Try LineSegmentDetector (LSD)