# OpenCV detect vertical line that is crossed by horizontal line

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to detect the position of a vertical line that is crossed by a horizontal line (x, y of top left corner) using `cv2.templateMatching`.

What I am getting is a strange position that is completely inaccurate. Also I would like to take into consideration when the vertical line is at the edge of the horizontal line.

Here is the code I am using:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
template = cv2.threshold(template, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

out = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(out)

# Draw detection
cv2.circle(image, (max_loc[0], max_loc[1]), 5, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

Here in the following image you will see the input, template, current output, expected output and the corner case when the vertical is at the edge of the horizontal line:

Link for image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QSmihmyu8LBCHOT3_A-Q1JSmFU7LlQhU/view?usp=sharing

Do you have any ideas for this problem? Any solutions? Using template match or other methods?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the template image have any padding around it, or is it literally a 1 px wide image?

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to detect top of vertical lines or you want the program finds any template you give it?

Comment: @Thomas Template image is 6x61 pixels, a small border of white around. I cannot upload images to stackoverflow server, that's why I merged them and placed on gDrive.

Comment: @AliEnt My goal is to detect the vertical line, anywhere on the horizontal line, even on the edge of horizontal line. The vertical line is moving left and right in a video.

Comment: [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60634986/11048887) may help.

Answer (score 1):

The code has two main parts. first detects vertical and horizontal lines and then it checks which vertical lines have intersect with any horizontal line.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

gray = cv2.imread('image.png')
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
minLineLength=100
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=1,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=80)

vlines = []
hlines = []
final_lines = []

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    if abs(lines[i][0][1] - lines[i][0][3]) < b / 100:
        # print("horizental")
        hlines.append(lines[i][0].tolist())
    else:
        # print("vertical")
        vlines.append(lines[i][0].tolist())

def ccw(p1,p2,p3):
    return (p3[1]-p1[1]) * (p2[0]-p1[0]) > (p2[1]-p1[1]) * (p3[0]-p1[0])

# Return true if line segments l1 and l2 intersect
def intersect(l1, l2):
    return ccw((l1[0], l1[1]), (l2[0], l2[1]),(l2[2], l2[3])) != ccw((l1[2], l1[3]),(l2[0], l2[1]), (l2[2], l2[3])) and ccw((l1[0], l1[1]), (l1[2], l1[3]), (l2[0], l2[1])) != ccw((l1[0], l1[1]), (l1[2], l1[3]), (l2[2], l2[3]))

# check intersect of each vertical lines with horizenal lines
for vl in vlines:
    for hl in hlines:
        if intersect(vl, hl):
            final_lines.append(vl)
            break

print(final_lines)
for line in final_lines:
    cv2.line(gray, (line[0], line[1]), (line[2], line[3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow('vertical line',gray)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

input image:

[image]

result image:

[image]