# How to find corners of plot using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find all four corners of the plot. I have tried using `cv.findcontours(mode=cv.RETR_EXTERNAL)` combined with the extremes (e.g., argmin() and argmax()), but the tick marks mess up the locations. I used Good Features to Track, and it doesn't appear to detect the corners very well. See image below and purple dots:

[Good features to track results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjVL5.jpg)

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img= cv.imread("image_path")
RGB = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# image thresholding
thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
cnt = contours[1]


# Good Features to Track
corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(thresh, maxCorners=4, qualityLevel=0.5, minDistance=10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

img_gftt_copy = img.copy()
for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    cv.circle(img_gftt_copy,(x,y),2,(255,120,255),-1)

cv.imshow("Good features to track", img_gftt_copy)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I try to find all four corners of the plot. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: by using `minAreaRect` is gonna give you the fitted rectangles for the contours found inside the image. choose the largest contour. or more complicated solution you may try [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633334/how-to-detect-corner-joints-that-connect-elements-on-images/60634986#60634986)

Comment: Thank you, Yunus. It doesn't quite work as it keeps tracking the outer edge of the tick marks. Though, while browsing the link you provided, I found that structural element does the trick!